# Install Package (.Net Core) on Linux Mint

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-mint, .net-framework, asp.net

I'm trying to install the .NET Core packages, but I have an issue and I do not know how to solve it.

I followed the steps on this page, but I get the below error:
https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/linux-package-manager/ubuntu18-04/sdk-2.1.202

[image: output from all command]

I'm a beginner in Linux. Is it something I'm doing wrong? Last week I had it

Answer (score 2):

I find the solution, first install using root, and if you use Ubuntu 18.04 you need add this script before:

```
wget -qO- https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | gpg --dearmor > microsoft.asc.gpg
sudo mv microsoft.asc.gpg /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/
wget -q https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/18.04/prod.list
sudo mv prod.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-prod.list

add-apt-repository universe
apt-get install apt-transport-https
apt-get update
apt-get install dotnet-sdk-2.1.202
```

here the source:

https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/download-archives/2.1.0-download.md#ubuntu-1804